# How is the localStorage is used within react.js?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Hello my question is simple. How can I save a single value to a localStorage; what data type should it be before it is stored. After I read 2 articles on localstorage with react and 4 answers on StackOverflow I still can't assimilate myself because the examples where on how to persist the whole state. Didn't find a documentation for react and localstorage also if someone give me a link it will be great. I wrote this code just for the example. Thank you in advance.

```
class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
           name: localStorage.getItem('name')
        })
    }


    changeName = e => {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            name: 'someName'
        }));
        localStorage.setItem('name', this.state.name);
    }




    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
                        <button onClick={this.changeName}>change</button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default List
```

Comment: What you try to achieve. What is problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `changeName` function you are setting state and after that setting the same state in `localStorage` **which won't work in your case**. This is because `setState` is `async` function, so it will take some time to execute and in that time your next code will get execute. In this scenario your `localStorage` will  get `empty value (first time) / previous value.`

To make it correct you can use [`callback`](https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c) in `setState` like,

```
this.setState({name: 'someName'},
  () => {localStorage.setItem('name', this.state.name)} //callback
);
```

Now you can have update value in [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) every time.

Comment: i just saw that problem... and actually this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few NPM packages like:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-localstorage

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-localstorage

These should help.

Comment: Thank you i was using other npm package and it was giving me error "localStorage.set is not a function" now everything is ok.